# How to extract Cipher Data into excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extract Data from URL.. there are some contact and mobile number in Cipher.. its look like Icone... I want to extract that numbers also there are one whatsapp link. i think its hidden in java script.. I want that link also...

here is  my URL Image, I mark with RED Box what data I want to extract...in Image
[image]

code is here

```
Public Sub GetTelNumber()
On Error Resume Next
Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim N As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim re As Object
Dim Str As String
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

        URL = "https://www.justdial.com/chengalpattu/Oasis-Pharma-Near-Saraswathi-Children-School-Revathypuram-Urapakkam/9999PXX44-XX44-181123145524-X8G7_BZDET"
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            s = .responseText

        End With

        Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        Set html = New HTMLDocument

        With html
            .body.innerHTML = sResponse
                Range("A2").Activate
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = URL
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = html.querySelector(".fn").innerText
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = Split(Split(Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "title>(.*)<"), Chr$(34), vbNullString)), "- ")(1), "  -")
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "streetAddress"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressLocality"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "postalCode"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressRegion"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressCountry"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = "WA:+" & Split(.getElementById("whatsapptriggeer").href, "phone=")(1)

        End With


End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Variant
Dim matches As Object

With re
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .pattern = pattern
    If .test(inputString) Then
        Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
        GetString = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        Exit Function
    End If
End With
GetString = "No match"
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveats:**

Please note:

1. Too many requests or too quickly will result in server offering you random pages.
2. I cannot realistically test all pages so your mileage on other pages may vary.
3. There are several places that would benefit from error handling being added but that can be a development piece.

---

**tl;dr;**

The following expands and improves upon the linked answer, and the code in your question, to handle multiple numbers being present.

The code added begins with `GetDetails` and then the resultant call stack. It uses the same principle of combining keys and values for mapping the tel numbers parts from the css instructions.

The parts of the `::before` for keys obtained by regex `-(\w+):before` (see highlighted rectangles in image below - 14 matches. The class mapping the actual elements comes from, for example, the `.icon-ji` and we only need the `ji` part for the dictionary key)

[image]

The parts of the `::before` for values obtained by regex `9d0(\d+)` (see highlighted rectangles in image below - 13 matches)

[image]

The subsequent subtraction of -1 from values to get the displayed digits on the page. Then the mapping of the first 13 into a dictionary followed by providing a hard coded 14 key value pair for the last key capture group

```
decodeDict(keys(UBound(keys))) = "+"
```

In order to determine how many telephone numbers are actually present, we extract the html for the telephone contact:

```
htmlToSearch = html.querySelector(".telCntct").outerHTML
```

And then use regex to match on either first multi-class value of each child span or the character ",". This is so we know where we need to split the decoded string to produce the required output numbers.

[image]

Note, in this case there are 24 matches of which one will be the "," between the contact numbers visible on the page:

[image]

We assume "," is the delimiter between tel numbers and that `number of tel numbers listed = count of "," + 1`.

Looking back at the html for tel contact we can see that the `","` sits outside of child spans so would not have been returned from `querySelector/querySelectorAll` on parent (with parent html placed in another HTMLDocument so as to leverage these methods); furthermore, any attempt to use *next* syntax e.g. `nextSibling` wouldn't preserve the required ordering of output.

`output` has our decoded string ready to chop into pieces e.g.

[image]

25 characters long comprising the two numbers.

groups array values tell us where to split this string as we know whenever we find a "," the next character is the start of the new number.

[image]

So, we loop the groups array and test the value at each position, use the position of each "," in groups to determine the slicing up of the string into the output array of telephone numbers:

```
Dim totalNumbers As Long, count As Long, results()

totalNumbers = UBound(Split(htmlToSearch, ","))
ReDim results(0 To totalNumbers)

For i = LBound(groups) To UBound(groups)
    If InStr(groups(i), ",") > 0 Then
        results(count) = Mid$(output, startPos, IIf(startPos = 1, i, i - startPos))
        startPos = i + 1
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next
results(totalNumbers) = Right$(output, Len(output) - startPos - 1)
GetNumbers = results
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTelNumbers()
    Dim html As htmlDocument, url As String, re As Object, s As String

    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    url = "https://www.justdial.com/chengalpattu/Oasis-Pharma-Near-Saraswathi-Children-School-Revathypuram-Urapakkam/9999PXX44-XX44-181123145524-X8G7_BZDET"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        s = .responsetext
    End With

    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set html = New htmlDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = s

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
        .Offset(0, 0) = url
        .Offset(0, 1) = html.querySelector(".fn").innerText
        .Offset(0, 2) = Split(Split(Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "title>(.*)<"), Chr$(34), vbNullString)), "- ")(1), "  -")
        .Offset(0, 3) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "streetAddress"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        .Offset(0, 4) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressLocality"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        .Offset(0, 5) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "postalCode"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        .Offset(0, 6) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressRegion"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))
        .Offset(0, 7) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, s, "addressCountry"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))

        Dim numbers()
        numbers = GetDetails(re, s)
        .Offset(0, 8).Resize(1, UBound(numbers) + 1) = numbers
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .Test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            GetString = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    GetString = "No match"
End Function

Public Function GetDetails(ByVal re As Object, ByVal responsetext As String) As Variant
    Dim decodeDict As Object, i As Long
    Dim html As MSHTML.htmlDocument, keys(), values()

    Set decodeDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set html = New MSHTML.htmlDocument

    html.body.innerHTML = responsetext

    keys = GetMatches(re, responsetext, "-(\w+):before")

    If UBound(keys) = 0 Then Exit Function

    values = GetMatches(re, responsetext, "9d0(\d+)", True)

    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        decodeDict(keys(i)) = values(i)
    Next

    Dim itemsToDecode()

    decodeDict(keys(UBound(keys))) = "+"

    itemsToDecode = GetValuesToDecode(html)

    GetDetails = GetNumbers(re, html, itemsToDecode, decodeDict)
End Function

Public Function GetMatches(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String, Optional ByVal numeric = False, Optional ByVal spanSearch = False) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object, iMatch As Object, s As String, arrMatches(), i As Long

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = sPattern

        If .Test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            ReDim arrMatches(0 To matches.count - 1)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                If numeric Then
                    arrMatches(i) = iMatch.SubMatches.item(0) - 1
                Else
                    If spanSearch Then
                        arrMatches(i) = iMatch
                    Else
                        arrMatches(i) = iMatch.SubMatches.item(0)
                    End If
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next iMatch
        Else
            ReDim arrMatches(0)
            arrMatches(0) = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
    GetMatches = arrMatches
End Function

Public Function GetValuesToDecode(ByVal html As MSHTML.htmlDocument) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, elements As Object, results(), class As String

    Set elements = html.querySelectorAll(".telCntct span[class*='icon']")

    ReDim results(elements.Length - 1)
    For i = 0 To elements.Length - 1
        class = elements.item(i).className
        results(i) = Right$(class, Len(class) - InStrRev(class, "-"))
    Next
    GetValuesToDecode = results
End Function

Public Function GetNumbers(ByVal re As Object, ByVal html As htmlDocument, ByVal itemsToDecode As Variant, ByVal decodeDict As Object) As Variant
    Dim output As String, i As Long

    For i = LBound(itemsToDecode) To UBound(itemsToDecode)
        output = output & decodeDict(itemsToDecode(i))
    Next

    Dim htmlToSearch As String, groups As Variant, startPos As Long, oldStartPos As Long

    htmlToSearch = html.querySelector(".telCntct").outerHTML

    groups = GetMatches(re, htmlToSearch, "mobilesv|,", False, True)

    startPos = 1

    Dim totalNumbers As Long, count As Long, results()

    totalNumbers = UBound(Split(htmlToSearch, ","))
    ReDim results(0 To totalNumbers)

    For i = LBound(groups) To UBound(groups)
        If InStr(groups(i), ",") > 0 Then
            results(count) = "'" & Mid$(output, startPos, IIf(startPos = 1, i, i - startPos)) 'to preserve any leading zeroes
            startPos = i + 1
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    results(totalNumbers) = Right$(output, Len(output) - startPos - 1)
    GetNumbers = results
End Function
```

Comment: that's alright :-) Do note my caveats. If you find another example of a a multi-number page that this script fails on then drop a link to it here. And sorry I didn't look at it until the weekend - busy work week.

Comment: [Link 1](https://www.justdial.com/Tiruvallur/Anand-Medical-Agencies-Opposite-Town-Police-Station-Tiruvallur-Ho/9999PXX44-XX44-110228120000-A5K9_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 2](https://www.justdial.com/Tiruvallur/Sunshine-Pharma-Near-DRBC-School-Tiruvallur-Ho/9999PXX44-XX44-140105203033-D7N7_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 3](https://www.justdial.com/Salem/Stardent-Meyyanur/0427PX427-X427-150413181421-J2N4_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 4](https://www.justdial.com/chennai/Medistar-Health-Care-Near-Madhuravoyal-Market-Bus-Stop-Maduravoyal/044PXX44-XX44-190713180450-Z6B2_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 5](https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Novartis-India-Ltd-Near-By-Alsa-Mall-Egmore/044PXX44-XX44-100607162013-R2L4_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 6](https://www.justdial.com/chennai/Sree-Sai-Enterprises-Near-Vanavampet-Church-Near-Bharat-Scans-Madipakkam/044P5407884_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 7](https://www.justdial.com/chennai/Subham-Medicals-Near-Pilot-Theatre-Backside-Royapettah/044PXX44-XX44-160923125707-D3N9_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 8](https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Medicine-Chamber-Opposite-Canara-Bank-Park-Town/044PXX44-XX44-000152780493-Q8O1_BZDET)

Comment: [Link 9](https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Delvin-Formulations-Pvt-Ltd-Accentuer-Sholinganallur/044PXX44-XX44-100814133400-V3M1_BZDET)

Comment: I’m busy at moment but will try the different use cases above.

Comment: Please Sir can you look in to my another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459739/extract-link-from-url-in-vba)
@QHarr