# Extract Link from URL in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have list of Javascript url in excel. that convert into another link ("Whatsapp Send me" Link)

once I log in into www.justdial.com with my mobile number

then i past following link into another new browser tab

https://www.justdial.com/webmain/cwaxp.php?dd=0657PX657.X657.110223165932.N1N6DC&wp=33EA66WE

this link automatically convert in to another link like

https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=919431348991

that another link show only once for a half second then goes to whatsapp web page

i don't know how to extract that automatically converted link into excel, I have list of  main links (First link) I want to extract that converted link for all. to get the all mobile numbers. anyone can hlep how to do with VBA

Comment: hello Sir @QHarr Please can you help out to solve this issue

Comment: you need to update this to include your code. I personally avoid doing anything involving whataspp and web-scraping/automation. If you are using a browser then simply pick up the document.url after the re-direct I think.

Comment: thanks sir. here I add some code.. but i want to work with google chrome if possible please guide me

Comment: Hiya, I would install selenium basic from github. You can then easily re-write your code using the examples.xlsm provided. Try that and use [edit] to include that code in your question above and explain where stuck. Delete the non answer you have put below. I personally stopped using selenium basic due to issues with Windows 10 but had no problems with earlier Windows installs.

Comment: @QHarr Please Sir Can you lookin my another problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816054/selenium-vba-excel-macro?noredirect=1#comment109339009_61816054)